# Bootstrap - Retain Button Styling when implementing Forms

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, button

I am using a Bootstrap Template (INSPINIA), and integrating it with PHP.

All of the sample data structures use buttons, but to make these interact with the server I need to change them to a submit and wrap them in a form.

Can I best retain the original bootstrap styling of a button, but gain the functionality of a form submit without having to amend bootstraps own CSS?

Original Bootstrap code:

```
  <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Add new task. " class="input input-sm form-control">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add task</button>
       </span>
   </div>
```

What I have ended up with:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
             <input type="text" placeholder="Add new task. " name="ToDo" class="input input-sm form-control">
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-white" value="Add Task" name="addToDo" />
          </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

The above code doesn't look the same and shows some odd behaviour on smaller devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the type of the button to submit, and you're good to go:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Add new task. " class="input input-sm form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add task</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

You have to add the form tag outside `input-group` to keep the styling:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Add new task. " class="input input-sm form-control">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add task</button>
       </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This works, but I still need to wrap the whole thing in a <form> tag, to be able to post with the input fields too. As soon as the form tag is added, the styling changes and the task button drops to a new line. I have tried using an inline form type also, but no luck. Surely everyone has this issue when adding forms over the bootstrap templates?

Comment: Excellent, you solved it! Thanks so much. The last </div> should be </form>, but apart from that its perfect.

Comment: @WelshJohn sorry, my mistake.